# nested each and conditional ifs

Tags: handlebars.js, mustache

This is my array of object. I am trying to use handlebars to create an output something like this. How can I achieve this? Is this even possible with handlebars.

```
var employee=[
           {name: "Ahmed", position: "head"},
           {name: "Matt", position: "TA"},
           {name: "Tai", position: "head"},
           {name: "Buddy", position: "instructor"},
           {name: "Collin", position: "instructor"}
       ]
```

### Head

```
   * Ahmed
   * Tai
```

### instructor

```
    * Buddy
    * Collin
```

### TA

```
    * Matt
```

I am able to print the names, using the #each helper

```
<ul class="people_list">
  {{#each people}}
    <li id="{{this.name}}">{{this.name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Update:

So I have updated the code and it still doesn't work

```
var employeeObject=employeeTemp
var context={people:employeeObject}
var html=template(context)
```

Here is the handlebars template

```
   {{#each people}}
    <h2>{{@key}}</h2>
    <ul class="people_list">
        {{#each this}}
            <li id="{{this.name}}">{{ this.name }}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper `array` to collect the data by `position`

```
var employee=[
  {name: "Ahmed", position: "head"},
  {name: "Matt", position: "TA"},
  {name: "Tai", position: "head"},
  {name: "Buddy", position: "instructor"},
  {name: "Collin", position: "instructor"}
];

var employeeTemp = [];

for(var e of employee) {
  if(!employeeTemp[e.position])
    employeeTemp[e.position] = [];
    employeeTemp[e.position].push(e);
}

employee = employeeTemp;
```

handlebars:

```
{{#each employee}}
    <h2>{{@key}}</h2>
    <ul class="people_list">
        {{#each this}}
            <li id="{{this.name}}">{{ this.name }}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Here is the catch, the `.position` value is dynamic, i.e., it can have different values. So if the position list is updated, the final output should also reflect this change. I am just trying to avoid hard coding the positions

Comment: I updated. But not tested. Please try this solution.

Comment: I tried the code but I am seeing the console log of the employeeTemp the way I want but when I render, it's not populating the template. I have updated my code